# What is a in-memory Queue in data structures?

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue

What is a in-memory Queue in data structures?

Edit: I still don't know if it was in-memory queue or just memory queue but any information about both would be good.

Comment: Where did you meet this name?

Comment: My professor in college. I asked what it was now I need to make a report about it.

Comment: Are you sure he didn't say "in-memory queue"?

Comment: Well since I'm not getting anything anywhere on that maybe it is in-memory queue. Am I violating any rules if I ask what that is in the comments?

Comment: Did you mean memory pools? (Just wondering)

Comment: Na, it was something with memory but definitely with queue.

Comment: An in-memory queue is, simply, a queue that you maintain entirely in memory (as opposed to spilling to disk or some other external storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In-memory queue is a regular queue which persists in your main memory.